# Counter triggered when node is deleted/created, but triggers also for changes of children

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

this is the structure of my firebase db:

```
/UserData
/DeviceMgmt
  /Counters
      /NumberOfAll:
      /NumberOfSelected
      /TotalDownloaded
    ...
  /Devices
      /pushId1
        /uid
        /toSelect=true (optional)
        /downloaded
        /lastDownload

      /pushId2
      /pushId2
       ...
```

My code:

```
exports.countNumberOfAllDevices = functions.database.ref('/UserData/DeviceMgmt/Devices/{pushId}').onWrite(
(change) => {
  const collectionRef = change.after.ref;// /UserData/DeviceMgmt/Devices/{pushId}
  const countRef = collectionRef.parent.parent.child('Counters/NumberOfAll');

  let increment;
  if (change.after.exists() && !change.before.exists()) {
    increment = 1;
  } else if (!change.after.exists() && change.before.exists()) {
    increment = -1;
  } else {
    return null;
  }

  return countRef.transaction((current) => {
    return (current || 0) + increment;
  }).then(() => {
    return console.log('counter /UserData/Counters/NumberOfAll updated.');
  });
});
```

is based on [functions-samples/child-count/](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/3b41b2e04d854a821a0149e1e5b0769bad397d67/child-count) where pushed messages are replaced by my devices, but my device have children and messages in the example are childless.

My problem is:

1.
When my device is created in java one writing is object creation, another one is update of its child, so the NumberOfAll counter increments by 2.

2. At every changes within {pushId} device the function is run useless because that does not change the number of devices.

Should I replace countNumberOfAllDevices with

two functions:

1. `incrementNumberOfAllDevices` with `onCreate` (after creating device object no child is created later)
2. `decrementNumberOfAllDevices` with `onDelete` (before deleting device object no child is deleted earlier)

OR

go deeper with snapshot reference from

```
/Devices/{pushId}
```

to

```
/Devices/{pushId}/uid
```

when uid is never changed between creation and deletion ?

My Java code that triggers the Cloud Function:

```java
testAddNewDeviceToDevices(String token) { 
  Device device = new Device( "Test", 0, token); 
  String deviceKey = dbRefDevices.push().getKey(); 
  dbRefDevices.child(deviceKey).setValue(device)
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() { 
      @Override public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) { 
        Log.e(TAG, "failed. Exception: ", e); 
      } 
    }); 
  }
```

Comment: The `change.after.exists() && !change.before.exists()` and `!change.after.exists() && change.before.exists()` are meant to select only creation and deletion. I'm not sure why either of those clauses would match for the creation of a lower-level node/value. Can you show the minimal Java code that triggers that behavior in this function?

Comment: Thanks Frank,This is strange. When I add device from console, it increments by one, when I run the code as below, it increments twice:

Comment: public static void testAddNewDeviceToDevices(String token) {

        Device device = new Device(
                "Test",
                0,
                token);

        String deviceKey = dbRefDevices.push().getKey();
        dbRefDevices.child(deviceKey).setValue(device)
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "failed. Exception: ", e);
                    }
                });
    }

Comment: That `testAddNewDeviceToDevices` only writes to the database once (`push()` does not cause a write), so I don't think that should cause the counter to go up twice.

Answer (score 0):

You should use onCreate and onDelete.  They were introduced in version 1.0 of the SDK for exactly the the case you're describing.  It will simplify your code drastically.

IMO, onWrite is not that useful.  It's kind of a legacy trigger from pre-1.0 days.